# how to capture the apex:inputField value on the front end?

Tags: apex, visualforce, apexinputfield

I have a picklist field that I am displaying on an old Visualforce page. I want to get the value that the user selects from the drop down to conditionally render another field based on their selection. I thought this would be as easy as a `onChange` function and pass the value and set the dynamic div's display style based on the value. When I try to pass the value, it is returned as null. I have also tried in the function with:

```
  function po(input, textid ) {
    console.log('--> ', document.getElementById('{!$Component.POBlock.potype}'));//brings in the entire picklist div
    console.log('--> ',document.getElementById('potype'));//j_id0:frm:poType
    console.log('--> ',document.getElementById(potype));//null
    console.log('--> ',document.getElementById("potype").value);//null
    console.log('--> ',input);//brings in the entire picklist div
    console.log('--> ',textid);//null

  }
```

I have also tried the other attribute functions such as onSelect, onFocus etc.

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="POBlock">
    <apex:inputField value="{!apexRecord.PO__c}" styleClass="form-control cs1" onChange="po(this, {!apexRecord.PO__c})" id="potype" />
</div>
```

Is there a good way to save the value of a `apex:inputField` on the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it - the JS function should be looking to the `event.currentTarget.value` rather than taking in the input and textId